# How to remove line if it contains "-" and numbers [0-9]

Tags: linux, unix

So if the file is

`abcd // no remove because it's has alphabets
a-c // no remove because it has numbers
1-1 // remove because it has both number and hyphen
a-1 // no remove because it contains alphabet
11 // no remove because it has no hypen`

Only remove "1-1" because it contains only numbers and "-"

Comment: So what have you tried? Note that we are here to help you with issues with your own code and attempt. We are _not_ here to do your work for you...

Comment: @arkascha I get that, Just for the record I did try to strip - with `awk -F- 'NF<='` but couldn't get regex to work with awk

Comment: Ok, all fine. I suggest you add that to the question. _All_ valuable information should be given right away in the question, not collected in comments. There is an `edit` button below your question. _Use it_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
grep -vE "^([0-9]*\\-[0-9]+)|([0-9]+\\-[0-9]*)$" input.txt
```

or if your input doesn`t contain a line with just "-" character you can simply use:

```
grep -vE "^[0-9]*\\-[0-9]*$" input.txt
```

Comment: can be simplified to `grep -vxE '[0-9]*-[0-9]*' input.txt` , avoid `"` unless needed...

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This is using perl and regex.

```
perl -lne '{if($_!~/\d{1,}-\d{1,}/){print $_;}}' input_file
```